# Types of Expo Project payment without detaching/ejecting

Tags: expo, payment

I am currently working on an Expo project that requires me to implement a payment function. I intend to use Stripe (I am open to other types of payment modes as well) but at the moment, the stuffs I have found require me to eject my expo project to expokit. Are there any payment modes that i can implement in expo project without ejecting/detaching it? Please do help (:

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/expo/stripe-expo, without ejecting to expokit. 
As It Uses the Stripe HTTP API in Expo without the DOM, node, or native dependencies.

Comment: Are there any examples of using it? Can't seem to find, because this package creates a token only I guess.

Comment: You can check from this - https://medium.com/@lyzhovnik/using-stripe-payment-service-with-react-native-and-fetch-4177c8d992cb

Comment: Can I check that once i created the token, and without ejecting the expo project, how do i use the token to pay? Do assist me on this T_T